# schedule tasks based purely on idleness, instead of data communication

Tags: python, distributed, dask

Using distributed to schedule lots of interdependent tasks, running on google compute engine. When I start an extra instance with workers halfway, no tasks get scheduled to it (though it registers fine with the scheduler). I presume this is because (from http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scheduling-state.html#distributed.scheduler.decide_worker):

> *"If the task requires data communication, then we choose to minimize the number of bytes sent between workers. This takes precedence over worker occupancy."*

Once I'm halfway running the task tree, all remaining tasks depend on the result of tasks which have already run. So, if I interpret the above quote right, nothing will ever be scheduled on the new workers, no matter how idle they are, as the dependent data is never already there but always on a 'old' worker.

However, I do make sure the amount of data to transfer is fairly minimal, usually just a small string. So in this case it would make much more sense to let idleness prevail over data communication. Would it be possible to allow this (e.g. setting a 'scheduler policy'? Or maybe even have a data-vs-idleness tradeoff coefficent which could be tuned?

*Update after comment #1:*

Complicating factor: every task is using the resources framework to make sure it either runs on the set of workers for cpu-bound tasks ("CPU=1") or on the set of workers for network-bound tasks ("NET=1"). This separation was made to avoid overloading up/download servers and restrict up/download tasks to a certain max, while still being able to scale the other tasks. However, according to http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/work-stealing.html, task stealing will not happen in these cases? Is there a way to allow task stealing while keeping the resource restrictions?

*Update 2*: I see there is an open issue for that: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1389. Are there plans to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

While Dask prefers to schedule work to reduce communication it also acknowledges that this isn't always best.  Generally Dask runs a task on the machine where it will finish first, taking into account both communication costs and existing task backlogs on overloaded workers.

For more information on load balancing you might consider reading this documentation page:

http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/work-stealing.html

Comment: Ah, then that might be the issue: "If a task has been specifically restricted to run on particular workers (such as is the case when special hardware is required) then we do not steal." all my tasks have custom restrictions, as I have different sets of workers for either cpu bound or network-bound tasks, and I don't want network bound tasks to run on the cpu workers (to avoid connections to up/download servers maxing out), and vice versa (to be able to scale my cpu-bound tasks to more than the max. number of connections). I'll update the question to reflect this situation.